# Layout Preview is not displaying when Material Design is updated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

**When I have update material design *1.7.0* to *1.8.0* then layout is not displaying.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate the IDE caches and restart. Then rebuild the whole project

Comment: I tried it, it works but after some time the re-rendering comes.

Comment: Share your code and layout files

Comment: I have attached the link. look into it.
https://farzansiddiqui.github.io/My-first-page/